# Excluding a component from css styling

Tags: css, xhtml, primefaces

I'm writing a simple xhtml page , i used template,css.. to style it .

in this page i have to show a message , my problem is that the message is styled with css and i don't want it to be styled here's the message code :

```
     <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />
```

So is there a way to exclude the message from my css styling .

Many thanks

Comment: Yes there is. But no you don't want to exclude trough CSS. A better approach is to add an unique class name. And style or remove style from this class and inheritance in the css file.

Comment: i'm new to css so i want the simplest way , if you can munch it please ,i mean simly exclud it

Comment: its only possible when you post an dump of your completly renderd page. post it on http://jsfiddle.net/ for example

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an exclude in css, you override the styles by addressing the element more specifically. If you a class or ID that you can select that only affects the element(s) you want, then you can add or overrule any styles already on it.

Add a class (for example) to your element so it looks like:

```
<p:messages id="messages" class="unstyled" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />
```

Then add whatever css you want to it.

```
.unstyled {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try h:messages instead. The standard components come with little style. Otherwise Peter is correct

Answer (score 0):

Though the answers above are accurate responses when the question is interpreted literally, I wanted to explicitly point out that the same effect can be achieved using the :not() pseudo-selector. :not() is now supported across all major browsers, so that makes this solution even more appealing for me. Here is what I would do:

```
<p:messages id="messages" class="unstyled" ... >
```

Then in your CSS file:

```
.selector-for-parent *:not(.unstyled) { /* whatever styles are being used across the children */ }
```

I know this is a really old listing, just happened across it and thought I'd point out that :not() is very handy for things like this. I know it is very similar to the first comment on the OPs post above (remove through CSS styling of a special unstyled class.)